# Smart way to reuse code for creating and updating entity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

I am currently developing a GraphQL API with NodeJS and I am looking for a smart way to share code between create and update entity functions.

**Context**

In my application, users are able to create and update their own flights (as a pilot) so I have two GraphQL input fields (`CreateFlightInput` and `UpdateFlightInput`) that are called from two different mutations.

**Problem**

When a user creates a flight, he must provide the plane he flew with. As the plane is represented by a Mongo ID, the API needs to check if the plane exists and if the user can see it. But when the user updates a flight, the same check is required (because the user can change the plane he used). As I am using two resolvers (mutations), I don't want to write the same code twice especially since I have the same problem for the passengers' field. You will ask me that if all the checks are the same, why am I using two different resolvers? The problem is that the server must perform certain actions during `create` but not during `update`. To summarize, we have two resolvers sharing some similar code but not only.

Do you have an idea of where I could write that code that I can reuse for both? I was thinking of a function with a boolean that indicates if we are editing or not but I would know if there is (are) better method(s).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, cant you create a function to do common operation and call it from both resolvers?

Comment: Maybe it will be easier for us to see each function then refactor them. Unless you want answers containing generic answers that you can google anyway.

Comment: @AmitBhoyar Thanks for your answer! That's what I've suggested. A function that takes 2 arguments: one containing a way to tell if we are editing or creating a flight and the second one with all the data. But does it make sense to have such a function in the project and in which "directory" should I put it? Is it more related to my entity or to GraphQL? Should it go to a `helpers` directory for example?

@NikkoKhresna Haven't coded the functions yet. I am still thinking of a smart and clean way to do it.

Comment: @lobodart, We have those functions in our resolver helpers, but trust your way to organize the code. I would look at it as simple nodejs function and pass  all required inputs as parameter.

Comment: @AmitBhoyar I will try this. Thank you!